# does output from LHS of pipe become an arg for RHS of pipe

Tags: command-line, bash, pipe

I'm having difficulty grasping how pipes work. Initially I thought of them as per the title but I couldn't get a simple example to work e.g.

```
mkdir temp
cd temp
echo "rubbish" > txtfile

ls | cat
txtfile # why does it not return "rubbish"?

ls | cut -c 2-4
xtf # result I expected.
```

I've read many pipe tutorials but none of them seem to go beyond "STDOUT of LHS becomes STDIN for RHS" and I'm left wondering what is STDIN of RHS. Does it become the first argument? Where does it slot in when RHS of pipe has options or more than one argument. Is there any kind of macro substitution taking place or is my thinking wide of the mark.

Given the above examples, does cut take its input from stdin but cat doesn't? How do you know which commands take their input from stdin and which don't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *what is STDIN of RHS. Does it become the first argument?*

No, they are completely separate things - see for example [What's the difference between STDIN and arguments passed to command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46372/whats-the-difference-between-stdin-and-arguments-passed-to-command)

> *does cut take its input from stdin but cat doesn't?*

In this case, they are both taking input from STDIN, and that input is the *string* `txtfile`. If you wanted to pass the *filename* `textfile` as an argument, you could use `xargs`:

```
ls | xargs cat
ls | xargs cut -c 2-4
```

but don't - see [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)

> *How do you know which commands take their input from stdin and which don't?*

You read the (fine) manual page for the command ex. `man cut`:

> ```
> NAME
>        cut - remove sections from each line of files
>
> SYNOPSIS
>        cut OPTION... [FILE]...
>
> DESCRIPTION
>        Print selected parts of lines from each FILE to standard output.
>
>        With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.
> ```

Comment: Thanks steeldriver. I'm a bit less confused now but long for some good old logical c syntax like cat(ls()).

Comment: @NoComprende well syntactically you **could** use a *command substitution* of the form `cat $(ls)` but you should not - for the same reasons as discussed in the link (i.e. it will fail for filenames containing whitespace and other special characters)